# dijit.dialog - Dynamically Sized dijit.Dialog Not Centered

Tags: dojo

I'm having issues with correct sizing and positioning of digit.dialog.

I'm using the built in logic of dijit.dialog to determine the dialog width and positioning as it's content can be any size. In addition, the dialog content needs to be set via the href tag.  If I start the browser window at 300px width, the right side of the dialog is all the way to the right. As soon as I manually resize the browser to the full width, and then shrink it, it adjusts the position. Sometimes it gets it correctly, but it's not consistent.

How do you get digit.dialog correctly so it displays it's content correctly for the first load time?

Please look at plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/FLO1VFWX2LbZeZAZuhYm?p=preview

```
new dijit.Dialog({ 
     id: "modal",
     href: "modal.html 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content needs to have a fixed size. Otherwise The position is calculated with an inner size which is not relevant anymore after the sizing.
Basically, when re-sizing, the position is calculated using the previous width.

By calling multiple times the resize method, the dialog will adjust its position (a sort of binary search of the best position/size)

```
dialog.show().then(function() {
    dialog.resize();
    dialog.resize();
    dialog.resize();
    dialog.resize();
    dialog.resize();                             
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/bhhAZlYOE6kIduxOX8cn?p=preview

But this is extremely ugly. You should consider giving a width of the content

Comment: Thank you for the response. The second method works. Giving the modal a fixed width or any type of width doesn't seem to fix the issue of responsive positioning on the initial load. I need the dialog to  display at 800px w but also be able to render correctly if the viewport is 400px.

Comment: did you try playing with min-width and max-width ?
What if you use width=80% ?

Comment: I tried max-width, min-width, and width with no success.

Let me also mention that this is only happening when you use ajax (href) to load content. If you load content inline, then everything works fine.